# If $A$ is a ring, why isn’t the ideal $A^{(\mathbb{N})}\subset A^\mathbb{N}$ finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noetherian

I’m using the definitions: $\underline{a}=(a_i)_{i\in I} \in A^I $ (where $A$ is a ring),

$$A^{(I)}:=\{ \underline{a} \in A^I \mid  |\mathrm{supp} (\underline{a})| <  \infty \} \subset A^I,$$

where $\mathrm{supp}(\underline{a}):=\{i\in I \mid a_i \neq 0 \} \subset I$.

> I’d like to understand why the ideal $A^{(\mathbb{N})}\subset A^\mathbb{N}$ isn’t finitely generated and therefore $A^\mathbb{N}$ isn’t noetherian.

This seems counterintuitive to me right now from the definitions.

Comment: hi dahemar. just to understand your intuition, if you don't mind me asking, why does it seem counterintuitive to you? in terms of solving the problem, one good way of showing that an ideal $I$ of a commutative ring $R$ is not finitely generated is the following:

Comment: find a _strictly_ increasing sequence of ideals $I_1<I_2<\dots$ such that $I=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}I_n$. if you can find such a sequence, do you see why $I$ will not be finitely generated?

Comment: in this case, you can take the ideal $I_n$ to be $\{\underline{a}:\operatorname{supp}(\underline{a})\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}\}$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Hi! It’s a bit hard for me to put my intuition into words but I’ll try what you just suggested, thank you!

Comment: To answer your question: yes, I can see why if you can find such a sequence then $I$ won’t be finitely generated… but in this case, we can’t write $A^{(\mathbb{N})}$ as a union over all the natural numbers, right…? I think that’s what I was finding counterintuitive.

Comment: hi dahemar; thank you for clarifying! yes, you're right that we can't write it as a union over each index *individually*. but the main point here is that any element of $A^{(\mathbb{N})}$ has finite support, and hence has support within some subset $\{1,\dots,n\}\subseteq\mathbb{N}$. that's why we can write is as a chain in this way; we just mirror the chain $$\{1\}\subset\{1,2\}\subset\{1,2,3\}\subset\dots$$ of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. does that make sense? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\underline a_1,\dots,\underline a_n\in A^{(\mathbb N)}$. Write $\underline a_i=(a_{i1},\dots)$ with $a_{ij}\in A$. There is $m\ge1$ such that $a_{ij}=0$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ and $j>m$. So we can write $\underline a_i=(a_{i1},\dots,a_{im},0,0,\dots)$. Since the multiplication in $A^{\mathbb N}$ is component-wise, a linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^n\underline b_i\underline a_i$ with $\underline b_i\in A^{\mathbb N}$ has the same property: all its components from $m+1$ on are zero. This shows that $A^{(\mathbb N)}$ is not a finitely generated ideal, since an element like $(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)$ with $1$ on the $m+1$ position, which obviously belongs to $A^{(\mathbb N)}$, can't be written as a linear combination of the supposed generators.

Comment: If $A$ is not unitary, then replace $1$ by a non-zero element. If $A$ is the zero ring, then your claim is false.